# OSX installing php 5.4

Tags: php, macos, macports

I downloaded Macports and run a command I get online, which would install php 5.4. It took a while, but seemed to work successfully. I then copied the php.ini.development and renamed it php.ini like suggested my Mac Ports, however when I type php -v in terminal I still see 5.3

What steps have I missed, what do I need to do to get it to use the php 5.4 :S

Comment: Download it from php.net and manually compile it.

Comment: Do a `locate php` and find out which locations you have a PHP binary in. Then reset your system path so it looks in the 5.4 folder first.

Comment: how do I reset my system path to point to the 5.4 folder

Answer (score 0):

Macports should updated your $PATH automatically. You can verify this by typing the following in your terminal window

```
~> which php
/opt/local/bin/php
```

If the path returned from `which php` is `/usr/bin/php` you'll need to updated your terminal session, by resetting system path

```
~> source ~/.profile
```

Try the `which php` again. If `/usr/bin/php` is still returned, add the following line to `~/.profile` file

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

to invoke your macports php 5.4 install from the command line, use php54, e.g.:

```
php54 -v
```